# Optional<Function<String, Boolean>> cannot be applied

Tags: java, function, lambda, option-type

Given an `Optional` that is holding a `Function<String, Boolean>`, I cannot apply this `Function` out of the `Optional` via map/flatMap:

```
Optional<Function<String, Boolean>> optTestFunction = Optional.of(x -> true);
optTestFunction.flatMap(f -> f.apply("Test")).orElse(false);
```

The IDE as well as the java compiler are giving me this error:

> no instance(s) of type variable(s) `U` exist so that `Boolean` conforms to `Optional<? extends U>`

Honestly, I do not get why it does not work like this - I have the feeling I am missing something obvious, but since even Google has not been able to help me with this one, I hope you can.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.map(..)` and not `flatMap`.

```
optTestFunction
    .map(f -> f.apply("Test"))
    .orElse(false);
```

A `flatMap` is used when the map step returns an Optional. It is not the case here.

Comment: Yes, this is the solution. I wasn't aware it would be THIS obvious - thank you very much.